# Grouping RadioButtons in a Single View, and Posting Back the Form Data Correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently working on an MVC application that involves multiple sets of radiobuttons in a single View.

When the View is posted back, I want the form data to be automagically parsed and typed so that the post back method in the controller is passed the options selected for each group of radiobuttons.

Here is some sample code to illustrate the point:

**Model**

```
public class SurveyViewModel {

    public List<SurveyQuestion> Questions { get; set; }

}

public class SurveyQuestion

{

    public string Question { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }

    public int Answer { get; set; }

}

public class Option

{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Survey()

    {
        List<string> questions = new List<string> { "Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3" };



        SurveyViewModel model = new SurveyViewModel {

            Questions = new List<SurveyQuestion>()

        };



        foreach (string question in questions)

        {

            List<Option> list = new List<Option>();

            list.Add(new Option() { Value = 1, Text = "Answer 1" });

            list.Add(new Option() { Value = 2, Text = "Answer 2" });

            list.Add(new Option() { Value = 3, Text = "Answer 3" });

            SelectList sl = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");



            model.Questions.Add(new SurveyQuestion {

                Question = question,

                Answer = 1, // TODO: Get this from DB

                Options = sl

            });

        }

        return View(model);

    }
```

**View**

```
    @foreach (SurveyQuestion question in Model.Questions)

    {
        <p>@question.Question</p>

        @Html.RadioButtonForSelectList(m => question.Answer, question.Options)

    }
```

**Helper**

http://jonlanceley.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/mvc3-radiobuttonlist-helper.html

If we were to just stick with standard MVC (no extensions), the `Html.RadioButtonFor` helper ends up outputting radiobutton groups that repeat a naming convention of Option[0], Option[1], Option[2] etc in the client.

This results in the first option from every group being grouped, the second option from every group being grouped, and so on.

Another way is to just examing the current request form data in the post back Action of the Controller, and parse it manually, but I had hoped to take advantage of MVC's ability to convert incoming data to typed parameters automagically - rather than do this myself.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `foreach` loop for collections as the model binder cannot write the correct markup in order for it to bind each item of your collection properly. You need to use a `for-loop`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count(); i++)
{
    <p>@Model.Questions[i].Question</p>

    @Html.RadioButtonForSelectList(m => Model.Questions[i].Answer, Model.Questions[i].Options)
}
```

You can inspect the markup written using a `forloop`. Each question is now indexed (e.g. `Questions[0].Answer`, `Questions[1].Answer` and so on) and so the model binder can do its job properly. I bet the radiobuttonlist helper won't even work with your current code as it writes out the options with the same name (e.g. question.Answer). So all options are treated as one group.

Comment: Glad to cure a long headache ;)